# JavaMail, no exception is thrown if the receivers mail are wrong

Tags: java

This codesnippet, sends a mail:

```
if (m.send()) {
    Log.i("MAIL SENDER: ", "Succesfully");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "The log file has been sent",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else {

    throw new MailException();
}
```

If the receivers mail isn't correct, e.g `example@gmail.co` instead of `example@gmail.com` the code runs into the first if-block. Why does this happend when the receivers isn't correct. Could anyone help me out here?

The mail settings is retrieved from SharedPreferences, and checked in this method:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
        emailAddr.validate();
    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When the user types in a email address in the textfield and hit Ok this is whats happening:

```
if (isValidEmailAddress(mail)) 
            editor.putString("Tomail", mail);
else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
```

This will only check if the mail contains a `@` and therefor its valid.

In my send method:

```
public SendMail(Context c) {
    this();


    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    _host = sharedPrefs.getString("host", null);
    _port = sharedPrefs.getString("port", null);
    _sport = sharedPrefs.getString("port", null); 
    _user = sharedPrefs.getString("mail", null);
    _pass = sharedPrefs.getString("pw", null); 

}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new GMailAuthenticator(_user, _pass));

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);





        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sending mail server can check if gmail.com exists or not. It cannot tell example is on that server or not. So it would send it. sending is successful. Hence no error.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do so in my code? examples would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because mail is an asynchronous protocol. Basically, mail isn't delivered to the destination, it's just delivered to your local mail server which does something smart with it. Eventually. In a few hours.

If something is wrong, the sender of the mail will get a mail with the error message, so you better make sure that address is correct.

This means receiver addresses are only checked at a later time. There is no way to validate them. You could do some simple pattern matching validation to check for broken domain names but that will stop working in a few months when the new top level domains become available and I get my `digulla@home` email address.

Comment: Thats right, I use my own email account as sender and reciever. And I get a "Cant deliver mail" message.

Comment: You can always write your own mail server in Java but there are cases when sending mail can take up to two days. A version of `m.send()` which blocks for up to two days probably isn't useful... :-)

Answer (score 1):

`validate()` used in `isValidEmailAddress()` method follows the syntax rules of RFC822. Unfortunately, "example@gmail.co" is considered a valid mail, thus it returned true. You can check the validity of mail using RFC822 over [here](http://mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate).

Documentation: [`validate()` of InternetAddress class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#validate%28%29)

---

**Update:** You will have to do additional validation, have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen I've edited my answer, please take a look.